# iCheck JS and CSS not working on server side scripting bootstrap datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable

I'm using bootstrap **server side scripting** to load data dynamically in datatable. On the main page ex. index.php everything working fine. but i've some checkboxes(inside the datatable with each row) on Ajax page ajaxData.php and in this page **iCheck**(a Plugin) js and css not working as its working in main index.php page.

Can anyone suggest me what to do in that case. do I need to reload its JS and CSS file on the ajax page? but if I need to reload that is not possible because my ajax page returning only JSON formatted data as you know about datatable server side scripting concept.

here is the example what I am doing https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side
I have a checkbox in first column of my code.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can recall js of iCheck just after loading your data table. For reference [iCheck doc](http://icheck.fronteed.com/).